# Automate raising ImproperlyConfigure if environment variable is missing

Tags: django

I have the following code in one of my views.py:

```
tl_key = os.getenv("TRANSLOADIT_KEY")
tl_secret = os.getenv("TRANSLOADIT_SECRET")

if not tl_key:
    logger.critical("TRANSLOADIT_KEY not set")
    raise ImproperlyConfigured

if not tl_secret:
    logger.critical("TRANSLOADIT_SECRET not set")
    raise ImproperlyConfigured
```

I know that if Django doesn't find `SECRET_KEY` or `DEBUG` environment variable, it will raise `ImproperlyConfigured` exception. Is there a way I can specify which env variables are required so that the said exception is raised automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list of items which is required in env file and paste this  in your main settings.py or dev settings

```
required_env_items=["TRANSLOADIT_KEY","TRANSLOADIT_SECRET"]             
for item in required_env_items:
   if not os.getenv(item):
      raise ImproperlyConfigured("please add {} in env file".format(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another environment variable defining your need, something like `APP_ENVIRONMENT=dev|prod`, that way you can check that var and raise ImproperlyConfigured or assign a default value in your code